# TypeError get_queryset() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am working on a accounting application...

I have a model called group which I want to make inside a specific company...

I mean different company will have different set of groups

So,I have tried some thing like this in my list view

```
class group1ListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = group1

    def get_queryset(self, pk):
        company_details = get_object_or_404(company, pk=pk)
        return self.model.objects.all().filter(Q(User=self.request.user) & Q(Company=company_details.id))
```

The User and Company fields are related through foreign key in my group1 model..

But getting this error:

> TypeError  get_queryset() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'

Can any one tell me what I am doing wrong in this??

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `pk` is not a parameter in the `get_queryset`, only the `self` is.

The positional and named parameters of the URL, are stored in `self.args` and `self.kwargs` respectively.

So you can fix the `get_queryset` to:

```
class group1ListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = group1

    def get_queryset(self):  # no pk parameter
        company_details = get_object_or_404(company, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return self.model.objects.filter(
            User=self.request.user,
            Company=company_details.id
        )
```

You can however boost efficiency by writing a single query (but the semantics is *slightly* different), like:

```
class group1ListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = group1
    allow_empty = False

    def get_queryset(self):  # no pk parameter
        return self.model.objects.filter(
            User=self.request.user,
            Company=self.kwargs['pk']
        )
```

We can add an `allow_empty = False` in case we want to raise a 404 when no such `group1`s can be found.

Your `urls.py` of course needs to pass the `pk` value, for example:

```
# app/urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$',views.group1ListView.as_view(),name='grouplist')
]
```

So you then can query the `group`s of a company with a path that has the `id` of the company. If this is the root URL, it is thus something like `host.org/123`

I think it is however advisable to rename the parameter to `company_pk`, since right now, you "hint" that this is the `pk` of the `group1` model, not of the `Company`. This confusion can result in queries that *look* correct, but are not. Most developers will find it strange if they see a query like

```
group1.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['company_pk'])
```

but not when they see

```
group1.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

Comment: @NiladryKar: how did you define an URL on this view?

Comment: @NiladryKar: you realise that in order to have a `pk`, the URL path needs to have such parameter? How else will you "derive" a pk?

Comment: 'url(r'^$',views.group1ListView.as_view(),name='grouplist'),' This is the url I have done...What change do I have to make in order to have a pk

Comment: Note that removing `get_object_or_404()` changes the behaviour slightly if the company doesn't exist - you'll get an empty list instead of a 404.

Comment: And there's no need to add `__id` in the second version.

Comment: @Alasdair: yes, although one can use `allow_empty = False` to raise a 404 in case it is empty.

Comment: @Alasdair: although that again is semantically a bit different, since a company can exist, but without any groups.

Comment: @Alasdair: as for the `__id`, I agree it is not *necessary*, but I prefer to do this since "*Explicit is better than implicit*".

Comment: Do I have to do somethingh like this in template 'href="{% url 'accounting_double_entry:grouplist' pk=company_details.pk %}'...

Comment: But as you say, `allow_empty` will give 404s whenever the queryset is empty, not just when the company does not exist. It's a bit misleading to say that the change will boost efficiency when it will change the behaviour as well.

Comment: I take your point about `__id` being explicit. Personally, I don't like it because `__` makes it look like Django will do an unnecessary join (although actually it's smart enough not to).

Comment: @Alasdair: even if it `JOIN`s are not removed, most databse systems are "smart" enough to factor it out :)

Comment: @NiladryKar: yes.

Comment: Now new error...'NoReverseMatch at /accounting_double_entry/2
Reverse for 'grouplist' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounting_double_entry/(?P<pk>\\d+)$']'  accounting_double_entry is the name of the app and 2 is the primary key of the company selected

Comment: @NiladryKar: you should add a `pk=...` in the `{% url ... %}` or `return redirect(..)` or `reverse(..)` calls for that view.

Comment: yeah I have done this in company details template '{% url 'accounting_double_entry:grouplist' pk=company_details.pk %}'

Comment: @NiladryKar: well there are still elements in templates, views, etc. that don't. The traceback, etc. might contain the exact location.